# Replace part of a line containing tabs

Tags: regex, bash, replace, sed, awk

How can one replace a part of a line containing tabs (\t) with sed, awk, or any other?

The line

```
    <property name="systemVersionDsvTes"                value="xxx"/>
```

or

```
\t<property name=\"systemVersionDsvTes\"\t\t\t\tvalue=\"xxx\"/>
```

should be replaced to:

```
    <property name="systemVersionDsvTes"                value="yyy"/>
```

or

```
\t<property name=\"systemVersionDsvTes\"\t\t\t\tvalue=\"yyy\"/>
```

The value **xxx** can vary and there are **one tab** before property name and **four tabs** before value. This name-value pair is the only one from a xml file.

I tried with the following:

```
ACTUAL_VERSION="\t<property name=\"systemVersionDsvTes\"\t\t\t\tvalue=\"4.1.9\"/>"
NEW_VERSION="\t<property name=\"systemVersionDsvTes\"\t\t\t\tvalue=\"4.1.10\"/>"
sed -i -e "s/$ACTUAL_VERSION/$NEW_VERSION/g" buildSIM.xml
```

and that resulted in an error: sed: -e expression #1, character 65: Unknow option for command `s' (s///?)

Whats wrong with the expression? Using GNU sed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message `Unknow option for command 's' (s///?)` refers to the "options" that can be added to the substitute command after the third slash. These options include letters like `g` to replace all occurrences of the pattern rather than just the first one, or `i` to ignore letter case. It usually hints that the pattern or substitution includes extra slashes. To deal with slashes in the pattern or the substitution they have to be escaped, too:

```
ACTUAL_VERSION="\t<property name=\"systemVersionDsvTes\"\t\t\t\tvalue=\"4.1.9\"\/>"
NEW_VERSION="\t<property name=\"systemVersionDsvTes\"\t\t\t\tvalue=\"4.1.10\"\/>"
```

Alternatively you can use a different character instead of a slash as the separator, for example `#`:

```
sed -i -e "s#$ACTUAL_VERSION#$NEW_VERSION#g" buildSIM.xml
```

Comment: Escaping both the forward slashes fix the error, then sed works as expected: sed -i -e "s/$ACTUAL_VERSION/$NEW_VERSION/g" file

Answer (score 1):

Good grief, just use awk and don't worry about all that sed nonsense:

```
$ cat file
        <property name="systemVersionDsvTes"                            value="4.1.9"/>

$ ACTUAL_VERSION='\t<property name="systemVersionDsvTes"\t\t\t\tvalue="4.1.9"/>'

$ NEW_VERSION='\t<property name="systemVersionDsvTes"\t\t\t\tvalue="4.1.10"/>'  

$ awk -v act="$ACTUAL_VERSION" -v new="$NEW_VERSION" '{gsub(act,new)}1' file   
        <property name="systemVersionDsvTes"                            value="4.1.10"/>
```

In reality, you might want to escape the "."s in the value in ACTUAL_VERSION with whichever approach you adopt since they match any character rather than a literal ".". Alternatively, in awk you can change to using a string comparison rather than an RE comparison:

```
$ awk -v act="$ACTUAL_VERSION" -v new="$NEW_VERSION" 'start=index($0,act) { $0=substr($0,1,start-1) new substr($0,start+length(act)) }1' file   
        <property name="systemVersionDsvTes"                            value="4.1.10"/>
```

There is no equivalent to that in sed.

Comment: Thank you for this very detailed answer. I've just tested both solutions and they worked well. If I escape the "."s, awk sends me a warning, but still works.

Comment: You didn't say what code you ran or what the warning was so this is guesswork but you probably tried the gsub() solution and awk's probably telling you you need 2 backslashes to escape the "." (e.g. "4\\.1\\.9") in an RE specified as a string since strings get parsed twice, once when read and then again when executed. You do not need to and so should not escape the '."s in the index() solution since index() works on string matches, not REs.

Comment: Using only one backslash "4\.1\.9" gsub() and index() return the same warning or alert, which is (translated from pt-br): `"awk: warning: escape sequence '\.' treated as normal '.'`. Using 2 backslashes "4\\.1\\.9", gsub() changes to "4\.1\.10" and index() works normal.

Comment: index() works just fine with `4\\.1\\.9`. The question is - what does `4\\.1\\.9` MEAN in a given context? When stored in a variable that is later used in an RE context (e.g. using `~ variable` or `match(...,variable)`) it means the 5 characters `4 . 1 . 9`. When stored in a variable that is later used in a string context (e.g. using `index()`) it means the 9 characters `4 \ \ . 1 \ \ . 9 `. When used in a constant RE context (e.g. `~ /.../`) it means the 7 characters `4 \ . 1 \ . 9`. So it all "works" but you need to understand what you're telling awk to do to get what you want.